# How to do a loop to match all rows with time tolerance in R?

Tags: r, loops, match

I have two databases DT1 and DT2:

DT1

| Date | service_id | route_id | id_course | stop_name | Departure_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-06 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 93 | 1 | Monet | 1899-12-31 05:14:00 |
| 2021-04-08 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 21 | 512 | Théâtre des Arts | 1899-12-31 08:44:00 |
| 2021-04-09 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 25 | 33 | Hameau de Frévaux | 1899-12-31 12:45:00 |
| 2021-04-09 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 13 | 2 | Hôtel de Ville | 1899-12-31 16:21:00 |
| 2021-04-06 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 120 | 348 | Rue de l'Eglise | 1899-12-31 08:05:00 |

DT2

| Date | service_id | route_id | trip_id | stop_name | Departure_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-06 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 93 | 4960 | Monet | 1899-12-31 05:14:00 |
| 2021-04-08 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 21 | 21203 | Théâtre des Arts | 1899-12-31 08:39:00 |
| 2021-04-09 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 13 | 1211 | Hôtel de Ville | 1899-12-31 16:19:00 |
| 2021-04-09 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 25 | 2334 | Hameau de Frévaux | 1899-12-31 12:47:00 |
| 2021-04-06 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 120 | 14542 | Rue de l'Eglise | 1899-12-31 07:59:00 |

I want to match the lines of DT1 with those of DT2 with the following tolerances:

** Exact tolerance on Date, stop_name, service_id and route_id

** Random tolerance on Departure_time: i.e. tolerance interval must change "n" times until all rows in DT1 match in DT2

the desired output is:

| Date | service_id | route_id | id_course | stop_name | Departure_timeDT1 | trip_id | Departure_timeDT2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-06 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 93 | 1 | Monet | 1899-12-31 05:14:00 | 4960 | 1899-12-31 05:14:00 |
| 2021-04-07 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 21 | 512 | Théâtre des Arts | 1899-12-31 08:44:00 | 21203 | 1899-12-31 08:39:00 |
| 2021-04-09 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 25 | 33 | Hameau de Frévaux | 1899-12-31 12:45:00 | 2334 | 1899-12-31 12:47:00 |
| 2021-04-09 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 13 | 2 | Hôtel de Ville | 1899-12-31 16:21:00 | 1211 | 1899-12-31 16:19:00 |
| 2021-04-06 | TCAR_R-1-31 | 120 | 348 | Rue de l'Eglise | 1899-12-31 08:05:00 | 14542 | 1899-12-31 07:59:00 |

I want to do this with a loop in R because my two databases are very large, I will be really grateful for any help!

Comment: You're welcome - happy to change the formatting and appreciate that you have put an expected output, but I still don't understand the question really. Could you explain a bit more what you mean by random tolerance?

Comment: What I mean by this is that I don't want to set a tolerance interval for example at [-1min , +3min ] because with that I will only have certain lines of DT1 that will match. But I want to repeat random intervals: [-1min, +3min], [-2min, +5min],
[-3min, +3min] ....
until each line finds its "unique" counterpart in DT2.

Comment: I think you can use `left_join()` with specifying your exact matching columns, then you can make a new column may be called `time_difference` to calculate the difference between departure time in DT1 and DT2, following that you can filter based on that column as you like.